# why #include directive doesn't have a semi-colon at the end of statement?

Tags: c, include

In C, semicolons (`;`) are used to indicate the end of the statement. Why do `#include` lines not need a semicolon?

Comment: Because it is not a C statement. It is a directive (instruction) to the preprocessor.

Comment: Its how C is designed and so do C++.

Comment: @Surya: Not a relevant comment I guess, after seeing the answers

Comment: You also don't need semi-colons after `#if`, `#else`, `#endif`, `#line`, `#undef`, `#define`, `#pragma`, etc.  In fact, a semi-colon after a `#define` is almost always a bug.

Comment: @Ant's Well, isn't that true enough. From example, java takes `;`. Ex: `import java.util.Scanner;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why there is no semicolons after preprocessor directives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845402/why-there-is-no-semicolons-after-preprocessor-directives)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#include` (and all other lines beginning with `#` like `#define`) is part of the [*preprocessor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). This is actually a separate programs that runs before the main compiler and does things like *include* files into the source and macro expansion.

Comment: "This is actually a separate program" - if you're using GCC it is. If you're using MSVC it isn't. The important point is that preprocessing is defined in the standard as a phase that occurs before the main compilation phase, and that has its own defined syntax not involving semi-colons. It's entirely up to the implementation how to organize the translation phases into programs.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` is processed by the pre-processor and the compiler doesn't see these statements. Hence `;` is not required at the end of statement.

Answer (score 2):

Because preprocessing directives are not statements.

Even not all statements are required to have a final `;`. For example:

```
int bla = 1;

if (bla) {
}
```

After the declaration of `bla` we have two statements: one `if` statement and one empty compound statement. There is no `;` but the program is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The directive is processed by the preprocessor  It is not a compiler, it is a simple text substitution processor.  Which uses end-of-line `(\n)` as a significant character, unlike the C compiler which just treats it as whitespace.  Also the reason that `\` at the end of the line has an effect.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what this line `Also the reason that \ at the end of the line has an effect` mean. Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: This is well covered in any C language book, do you have one?

Comment: Yes I do have one, which is K&R.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "whatever.h"
```

It just replaces that line in your source file with "whatever.h". So you don't need to put `;` at the end of "whatever.h". The pre-processor will give you a warning and ignore it.

Comment: Can you explain me `The pre-processor will give you a warning and ignore it` the statement in your answer?

Comment: I think the idea is that 'if you write `#include "whatever.h";`, the pre-processor will give you a warning and ignore the semi-colon'.

Comment: While reading the tokens once it sees #, it looks for keywords (include, define, pragma etc) after that. Specifically for include, the next tokens are followed by < or a single quote (") and the name of the file and then the corresponding closing token > or ("). It expects the next character after that to be a new-line. Otherwise, it gives you a warning for the extra token which it couldn't understand. As @JonathanLeffler noted "ignore it" meant for ; not for the header file.